# How to go back to (currentView-2) UIViewController in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to come back to the previous `UIViewContoller`.

The way I do it is by using this piece of code

**.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
```

**.m**

```
[Event saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    self.viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    NSLog(@"Viewcontroller stack : %@", self.viewControllers);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.viewControllers.count-2] animated:YES];


    }];
}];
```

In `self.viewControllers` I store the UIViewController stack, but it prints only the current one, say  . In the hierachy, I have UINavigationControllers in various views.

Additionally, the app crashes with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
MyEventsViewController *tomyevents = [[MyEventsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyEventsViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:tomyevents animated:YES];
```

And I get following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

EDIT 2:

I am using modal segues

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buhPy.png)

Comment: If you are using a navigation controller, it is already managing the view controller stack for you. Don't push a view controller, pop back

Comment: This seems to be a navigation controller. That means it uses push and pop. The way to go "forward" is `pushViewController`. The way to go "backward" is `popViewController`. You should not have any need to manipulate the navigation controller's `viewControllers` or keep any kind of list.

Comment: It feels - to me - like you need to clearly understand the concept of *stacks* - specifically a tack of view controllers. Like a `UIView` hierarchy, you have the same for that with `UIViewControllers` - when they a used within a `UiNavigationViewController`. Simply push another on the stack - or simply pop one off it inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Reaching into your navigation controller's stack and trying to push a view controller from the middle of the stac onto the top is very wrong, and will cause bad things to happen.

Think of a navigation controller stack as a stack of plates. You can push a new view controller onto the top of the stack, or pop off any number off the stack to reveal one from below, but you cannot take a view controller out of the middle of the stack and put it on top. That will cause the stack to fall over and break.

To pop to a specific view controller, use `popToViewController(_:animated:)` You pass that method a pointer to a view controller from the current stack that you want to be at the top of the stack. The navigation controller will pop off as many view controllers from on top of it as needed to make it the new top view controller.

### EDIT:

If you know you want to pop to the n-2 view controller, your code might look like this:

```
[Event saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSArray *navStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    //Fetch the count-2 view controller from the stack
    if (navStack.count <3) { 
      return;
    }
    UIViewController *nMinusTwo = [navStack objectAtIndex: navStack.count-2];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController: nMinusTwo, animated: YES];


    }];
}];
```

Comment: I think I understood it. Can It be with something like this? `MyEventsViewController *tomyevents = [[MyEventsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyEventsViewController" bundle:nil];[self.navigationController popToViewController:tomyevents animated:YES];` ?

Comment: No, because that will be the a new instance of the view controlller.  You need the existing instance from the `viewControllers` array

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I'm getting out of practice with Objective-C, but I think I got that right...

Comment: Hi duncan ! Your code is correct, but for some reason it doesn't pop because when I NSLog navStack shows me 1, which is the current ViewController :( . I use ModalSegues , the new iOS 13 ones. Probably there’s something I’m missing here.

Comment: When you log the navigation stack it shows that it only contains one view controller? Then you have a navigation stack that only contains its root view controller, and you can't pop **anything**. You say you're using Modal segues. That sounds like you're not using navigation controllers at all. Edit your question to show how you are creating and displaying your view controllers.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my storyboard. Not sure if its readable, but I have it full of navigation controllers.